# php help - sort multidimensional array buy using another array

Tags: php, arrays

I hope somebody can help me, I need to order array No.1 based on the position of array no.2 , using the `array1->id` to `array2->products_id`

Array No.1

```
{"products":[{"id": 9847760515,"title":"Some Dress"},{"id": 10769647619,"title":"Shirt"}]}
```

Array No.2 where the order is: (position":x)

```
{"collects":[{"id":38447047939,"product_id":10769647619,"position":1,"sort_value":"0000000001"},{"id":25425594499,"product_id":9847760515,"position":3,"sort_value":"0000000003"}]}

foreach ($sorted_array as $product) {
 echo $product['name'];
}
```

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function which will take both arrays and order them by whatever format you need it to be in:

```
/**
* sort_array will take two arrays and will sort the first based on the second
*
* @param $array the array you want to reorder
* @param $order the array with the pattern
*
* @return array_multisort with reordered array
*/
function sort_array(&$array, $order, $dir = SORT_ASC) {

    // create an empty array here
    $sort = array();

    // loop through the main array
    foreach ($array as $key => $row) {
        $sort[$key] = $row[$order];
    }

    array_multisort($sort, $dir, $array);
}
```

Using `array_multisort` you can "sort multiple or multi-dimensional arrays." For more information on that you can read it on [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php); with further information on how it can be used.

---

I based this answer with previously [answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2699153/1527252) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Hi Samuel, thanks for the answer, I had already seen the other answer before, but can you show me an example using my arrays?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function supplying it with order from the second array:

```
$sort = array_combine(
    array_column($array2, 'product_id'),
    array_column($array2, 'position')
);

usort($array1, function ($a, $b) use ($sort) {
    return $sort[$a['id']] - $sort[$b['id']];
});
```

We prepare sorting dictionary (`$sort`) by using [`array_combine`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) and [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) functions. Pay attention, that in order to use [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) function you have to convert your JSON to an array of arrays (pass `true` as the second argument of [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function).

Here is [working demo.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/01f6cda593558f830768e5329a8835f41acb9de1)